# How to access third table data from eloquent relation between two tables in laravel?

Tags: laravel

i am sorry, if my question not make sense...

i have these two tables Area, and Address and are related via foreign key... here is the area and address models

```
class Area extends Model
{

    protected $table='areas';

    public function sections(){

        $this->hasMany(Area::class,'area','id');
    }

    public function address(){
        $this->belongsTo(Address::class,'id');
    }
}

class Address extends Model
{
    protected $table='address';

    public function area(){
        return $this->hasMany(Area::class,'id');
    }
}
```

and i have a third table section which is connected to area table.

my question can i make eloquent relation that can access the data of address table from the section "section table connect with area not address"

```
class Section extends Model
{
    protected $table ='sections';

    protected $fillable =[
        'sec_code',
        'area',
        'id',
    ];


    public function beneficiaries(){
        return $this->hasMany(Beneficiary::class,'ben_sec','id');
    }

    public function area_sec(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Area::class,'area');
    }

  public function address(){
  // need the eloquent relation if could
 }

}
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call it as a property not a method:

```
$model->area_sec;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data with access it from your Area relation first, so the code will be like this:

```
class Section extends Model
{
    protected $table ='sections';

    protected $fillable =[
        'sec_code',
        'area',
        'id',
    ];


    public function area_sec(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Area::class,'area');
    }

    public function address(){
        return $this->area_sec->address;
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you, it's works, but i got this    #eagerLoad: array:1 [▼
    "address" => Closure {#181 ▶}
  ]
  #loc how can i access this eagerload array

Comment: you get that after you call that method?

Comment: I am getting same error with above code : Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::addEagerConstraints()